# TSQL: Why some functions generate aggregate function error and others not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

Based on [TSQL group by generate duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44787970/1250185) code,

I don't understand why I can make `SUM`,`CAST`, and some other TSQL function
without any error but MIN and MAX generate an error:

`Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.`

I also tried to change `MIN()` with something like:

```
... WHEN g.dateCreated = (select MIN(dateCreated) from goodies gt where gt.customer_id=g.customer_id) AND ...
```

But it create the same error.

So why I got this error with some function and how I can prevent it?

```
with myQuery as (
SELECT
c.name,
c.id,
total_price = sum(case
      when g.dateCreated >= '20160601' and g.dateCreated < '20170601'
        then cast(g.price as decimal(20,2))
      else 0
      end),
total_tax = sum(case
      when g.dateCreated >= '20160101' and g.dateCreated < '20170101'
        then cast(g.tax as decimal(20,2))
      else 0
      end),
first_cmd = SUM(case
      when g.dateCreated = MIN(g.dateCreated) -- Error
      then cast(g.command as INTEGER)
      else 0
      end)
from customers c
  left join goodies g
    on c.id = g.customer_id
group by
    c.name
  , c.id
)
select count(*) from  myQuery;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code causing the error:

```
first_cmd = SUM(case when g.dateCreated = MIN(g.dateCreated) -- Error
                     then cast(g.command as INTEGER)
                     else 0
                end)
```

You have a `MIN()` nested in a `SUM()`.  That is not allowed.  It is unclear what you want to do, so it is hard to suggest an alternative.

If I had to guess . . .

```
select . . .
       first_cmd = SUM(case when g.dateCreated = mindc -- Error
                            then cast(g.command as INTEGER)
                            else 0
                       end)
from customers c left join
     (select g.*, min(g.dateCreated) over (partition by g.customer_id) as mindc
      from goodies g
     ) g
     on c.id = g.customer_id
. . .
```

Comment: I would get the first number in the command column based on dateCreated. well, when I removed "sum" I need add too many group by and generate duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
with firstQuery as (
SELECT c.name, c.id, MIN(g.dateCreated) minDateCreated
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN goodies g
    on c.id = g.customer_id
GROUP BY c.name, c.id
) ,myQuery as (
SELECT
c.name,
c.id,
total_price = sum(case
      when g.dateCreated >= '20160601' and g.dateCreated < '20170601'
        then cast(g.price as decimal(20,2))
      else 0
      end),
total_tax = sum(case
      when g.dateCreated >= '20160101' and g.dateCreated < '20170101'
        then cast(g.tax as decimal(20,2))
      else 0
      end),
first_cmd = SUM(case
      when g.dateCreated = f.minDateCreated
      then cast(g.command as INTEGER)
      else 0
      end)
from customers c
  left join goodies g
    on c.id = g.customer_id
  left join firstQuery f
    on f.id = c.id and f.name=c.name
group by
    c.name
  , c.id
)
select count(*) from  myQuery;
```